# Sitecatalyst Business requirements to capture sorting of column headers on a search result page

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have a business requirement to capture sorting of column headers on a search result page. What would be the best design and implementation strategy from analytics perspective  with assuming we could have 10+ columns on Search Results page?

Could you please help me with the proper guidance?

Comment: What metrics do you want to see? There a few ways to handle this depending on what your business is trying to see from this data. Do you want to see each column name as a line item or a complete sort string for example?

Comment: Actually I am looking for Search Result page with shorting.Also Yes I am looking for Complete shorting.

Comment: @user2710991 can you provide more details? It's difficult to guide you if you don't tell us what you're trying to do with the data.